# ubuntu 20.04 stopped working and does not restart anymore

Tags: boot, dual-boot

my ubunutu 20.04 stopped working suddenly. I get the following error messages when trying to turn on the laptop.

g sector 0x74706da0 from 'hd0'.
error: failure reading

after a while a new screen appears which tells me:

GNU GRUB version 2.04

Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.

grub>

Does anyone know what the problem could be and how to fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Try typing "instmod normal" and then "normal".

Comment: Welcome to AU. You must boot the Live USB/CD because the disks can only be checked if they are not mounted. Determine the type of file system the disk is and run e2fsck if its ext2/ext3/ext4. Otherwise use fsck. Command (for example): (e2)fsck /dev/hd0